# Measuring/evaluating the performance in IE

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I need to understand the report generate by the performance/profiling tab of chrome/internet explorer. The task is to find the possible memory leaks and architectural flaws in the application. My application loads perfectly fine in chrome and firefox but in internet explorer there's a humongous difference in performance. 
For example, it takes around 3 second for a page to load in chrome and firefox and the same page takes 23 seconds to load in internet explorer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to run the new profiling session from the memory tab and take snapshot of it.

Then try to import the other snapshot and try to compare it.

Generally, the developer tools in IE and Edge provides the similar functionality.

I try to find the documentation for IE developer tools which have basic details.

[image]

So you can try to refer the link below which is for Edge to get more information about it.

[Memory Tab (Developer tools)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/memory)

Comment: I am looking at the same place but I am finding it hard to get the meaning out of the report that I am getting. I need to identify the places to improve the application performance in internet explorer as it is running good in all the browser. e.g. it takes 3 seconds to load in chrome compare to IE's 23 sec

Comment: Many other things can affect the performance. Like which type of contents, scripts, graphics, data you are trying to load in browser. Each browser has its own engine which have different performance ratio. So you also need to check those things. Besides that you can refer the documentation link and try to understand the features and functionality of it may help you to find the issue.